# ValueType Not Getting Garbage Collected?

Tags: c#, collections, garbage

```
 public struct LocalTLS : IDisposable
{
    public byte[] bArr;
    public string str;
    public LocalTLS(int k)
    {
        str = "Labamba";
        bArr = new byte[20000];
    }
    public void Dispose()
    {
        MessageBox.Show("In Dispose");
        //Thread.FreeNamedDataSlot("jaja");
        int k = 90;
        k += 90;
    }
} 
private void buttonTLS_retreive_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        LocalTLS lts = new LocalTLS(1);
}
```

After the click event returns I expect the Dispose call but THAT NEVER HAPPENS, Can Some one explain. I do not want to do any manual steps like calling Dispose or do using. I want that to happen automatically.

Well thanks for all your answers, I wanted to implement a a class for LocalDataStoreSlot, that will automatically free the Slot and it goes out of scope, as shown in the commented code. This will free the developer from remembering to 
call dispose, wherein the actual FreeNamedDataSlot(...) happens. Seems like that is not possible

Comment: Here's my only follow up question: do you know when and how to use `IDisposable`? [Here's a link, just in case](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.aspx)

Comment: could you explain why you expect the Dispose method to be called after the event returns?

Comment: *I expect the Dispose call but THAT NEVER HAPPENS* - intended behavior, your expectations are simply wrong. =D

Comment: Dispose() is not called automatically when lts goes out of scope. Either call it manually or wrap it in a "using" block.

Answer (score 1):

The CLR does not perform garbage collection all the time, otherwise your program will be very slow because it is performing GC. To perform GC, the CLR has to suspend ALL the threads before reclaiming memory used by out of scope objects. That is a very big performance impact.

The CLR will perform GC and call the object's Dispose method when necessary. Do not call the object's Dispose() method unless you have a good reason. If the object is associated to native system handles, network connections, file handles etc., those are good reasons to use the `using` keyword or call it's `Dispose()` method. Generally the CLR will GC objects that are out of scope fast enough such that your application will not run out of memory.

I understand your concern, you believe that byte[20000] is a significant memory footprint to your application and you want to control your memory usage carefully. But this is not C++. The CLR will automatically manage memory for you. In my past 7 years of .NET develop I have only come across one application where the default GC is not fast enough and I have to call Dispose() on objects manually. So in short, just hand over memory management to the CLR - it does a very good job.

p.s. if you're interested in how GC works internally, there are a number of in-depth articles online. Just search - you'll find them.

Answer (score 0):

You've to wrap your object declaration inside `using` like this:

```
using(LocalTLS lts = new LocalTLS(1))
{
   // use lts here

} // at this point, the Dispose method is called.
```

or call `Dispose` method manually:

```
lts.Dispose();
```

Also, the `Dispose()` method is automatically called when there is no reference to `lts` in the code, by the Garbage Collector.

Comment: What if I do not want to use using as I could be modifying values

Comment: @Dr.sai, see the last line of my answer for that

Comment: Nor do I want to call dispose, If Microsoft say they will be automatically collected then I expect a call on the Dispose, Thanks

Comment: Nope dispose is never called as that message box never comes

Comment: @Dr.sai that's what Amit was trying to tell you - it won't be called. You need to use a `using` block or call it yourself. That's *just how it works*. It is not a destructor.

Answer (score 0):

Its a struct, it lives on the memory stack not the memory heap. So its not going to be collected by the garage collector like objects do, so the GC will not call the dispose method. Your struct "LocalTLS " will be freed up and taken off the memory stack when your method ends. When it does this, it does not look for the IDisposable interface.